# How can we apply conditional include using includeProperties in generaic repository pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

We are using Entity framework along with the generic repository pattern.

When loading multiple entities we use includeProperties string filter in generic repository pattern.

Following is the code I have in my service class,

```
customerRepository.Get (filter: c => ! c.IsDeleted, includeProperties : "Orders");
```

Following is the code I have in my Generic Repository

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "",
            Func<TEntity, TEntity> selectColumns = null)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (selectColumns != null)
    {
        query = query.Select(selectColumns).AsQueryable();
    }

    query = includeProperties.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));

    return orderBy != null ? orderBy(query).ToList() : query.ToList();
}
```

It is possible that a customer can have multiple orders which are already deleted. However using above includeProperties we are only  able to load all orders of a customer.

How can we load only non deleted orders of a customer?

i.e. How can we apply conditional include using includeProperties in generaic repository pattern?

We tried the code below but it did not work:

```
customerRepository.Get (filter: c => ! c.IsDeleted && ! c.Orders.IsDeleted, includeProperties : "Orders");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that it is not currently possible to filter which related entities are loaded. Include will always bring in all related entities. 
>   [Msdn Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#explicitFilter)

In this repository pattern you cannot do this with this specified method.

You can extend your repository to return IQuerable and do the same.

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAsQueryable(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
{
    return _dataContext.TEntity.Where(where).AsQueryable();
}
```

[See reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963070/deep-loading-data-mvc-entity-framework-repository-pattern)

Request this feature [here](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015345-allow-filtering-for-include-extension-method)

**In order to filter child collection you need something similar to this.**

```
var anonymousProjection = dbContext.CustomerEntity
                                 .Where(c => ! c.IsDeleted)
                                 .Select(x=> new 
                                  {
                                       customers = x,
                                       orders = x.Orders.Where(h=>h.IsDeleted)
                                  }).ToList();
```

[Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801565/entity-framework-filter-lambda-navigation-properties/33801710#33801710)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that it is not possible to filter related entities.  However for the anonymous projection in your comment above is not helpful due to below reason:     

    1: We are using entity framework to load the entities and save the same, by changing required properties values only.
    2: In the case of anonymous project above, the customer object is not an object which is tied with dbContext, however it is anonymous.
    3: Because of this we are not able to modify and save the customer objects. It only helps during select queries.

Comment: You could still try `var customers = anonymousProjection.Select(x=>x.Customers).ToList()` this will convert to strongly typed without losing the relation with orders entities. Still this is tracked by context and you can still make changes and save to database